# trouble resizing image in "cards with overflowing images layout."

Tags: html, css, layout

I am using a card-based layout from codepen and each card contains an image. On codepen, I am able to resize and adjust the image that appears on the card with no issues. However, when implementing the same exact html code and stylesheet on my browser, the image I am resizing does not respond to any changes made to code contained within "{ img" like it does on codepen. While I was able to adjust the margins of the card wrap to make things appear as I desire, I am wondering what the root of the issue is with my code. Thanks!

```
<!--DOCTYPE html-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
<html>
    <link href="home.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <title>Purple Moss</title>
            <!-- inspiration: https://dribbble.com/shots/3784003-Plant-description-page -->
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-pic-wrap">
      <img src="https://imagizer.imageshack.com/v2/320x240q90/922/MeU4GZ.png" alt="A leafy plant">
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <h3>summary:</h3>
      <p>Blossom dorset heath scabious ipsum. Grape hyacinth bee balm bird of paradise obedient plant african lily lily. Spring foxglove florist’s nighmare primrose.</p>
      <p><a href="#0">So leafy</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-pic-wrap">
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1145795/plant-4.png" alt="Some pointy plants">
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <h3>Some pointy ones</h3>
      <p>Florem ipsum sugarbush bloom red rose waxflower coneflower ginger. Saxifrage forget-me-not obedient plant.</p>
      <p><a href="#0">I'll take 10</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</html>
```

/* CSS */

```
$b-r: 5px;

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}
.wrap {
  height: 100%; 
}
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 80px 0;
  border-radius: $b-r;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}
.card-pic-wrap {
  border-radius: $b-r 0 0 $b-r;
  width: 200px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f5e4b5, #a19ad9);
 img {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 3em;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -175px;
    width: 350px;
    -webkit-box-reflect: below -1px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(90%, transparent), to(rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.15)));
  }
}
.card-content {
  padding: 3em 4em 2em;
}
h3 {
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
}
a {
  background: #f5e4b5;
  color: #15077d;
  padding: 0 25px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  &:hover {
    background: #15077d;
    color: #f5e4b5;
    border: 2px dotted #f5e4b5;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 790px) {
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  .wrap {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  .card {
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
  .card-pic-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: $b-r $b-r 0 0;
    img {
      bottom: 20px;
      position: relative;
    }
  }
  .card-content {
    padding: 2em 2em 1em;
  } 
}
```

Comment: what is your broblem? https://jsfiddle.net/mvrqow2t/

Comment: when i change the px size, margin-left, or any other elements contained within "img {" in the css, the image does not change size or positioning in the browser. these changes do work in codepen.

Comment: never mind, answered my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I think I found the issue.
The template code I was using on codepen contained the "img {" within the ".card-pic-wrap {" and did not close off "img {" with closing bracket "}." Rather, it closed off both of these elements with double brackets, which worked fine in codepen but not in browser.